# Error starting VM - CentOS Kernel Panic - not syncing: Attemped to kill

Tags: linux, kernel, virtual-machine

Clone a VM in VirtualBox and restore from VMware, but starting a VM seemed like an error.

[image]

Comment: Ok, already updated

Comment: Looks like you are trying to start an image which had been suspended but now don't have the swap partition which held the suspended data.

Comment: Have a solution? or should I redo the backup process?

Answer (score 0):

Go back and clone your VM again as a Full, rather than Linked, clone in VirtualBox.  This will do a deep copy of the VM's disk images and will take care of the missing swap and root devices.